# InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'. Parameter name: SelectedIndex combo box VS 2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, combobox

I am getting this error: **InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'. Parameter name: SelectedIndex** in this part of my code:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con.Open()
    ds = New DataSet
    tables = ds.Tables
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Questions]", con)
    da.Fill(ds, "Questions")
    Dim view1 As New DataView(tables(0))
    With ComboBox1
        .DataSource = ds.Tables("Questions")
        .ValueMember = "ID"
        .DisplayMember = "ID"
        .SelectedIndex = 0
    End With
    con.Close()
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = NumericUpDown1.Value
    NumericUpDown1.Value = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex
    NumericUpDown1.Maximum = ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1
End Sub
```

The above code works with my friend's VS 2010 but when I transferred the exact same code to VS 2008, it's throwing me that error. I tried inserting an if else statement If ComboBox1.Items.Count >0 But it's still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: What is `Items.Count` when the exception is thrown?  Presumably it is 0, which indicates that there are no items, which means that you can't select the first item.  What's the point of selecting the first item after binding anyway, given that that's what happens by default?  If you want to select no item then you set `SelectedIndex` to -1.

Comment: I asked two questions and "it's still throwing the same error" doesn't answer either of them.

Comment: Hi @jmcilhinney, I have made it work. the problem is with the data source and not the code. Thanks, anyway

Comment: The problem was with your assumption that the control would contain at least one item.

Comment: So what can you suggest?

Comment: I can't really suggest anything with confidence because you haven't actually explained what you're trying to achieve and your code doesn't really make sense. As I said, setting the `SelectedIndex` to 0 after binding is pointless because that's the default behaviour. The fact that you're setting it again from a `NumericUpDown` right after makes it doubly pointless, but I have no idea why you're doing that.